# Toggle logical NOT operator based on a boolean value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to think of a better way to write the below Javascript/NodeJS code without having to check the value of the boolean using an `if` statement. I know this can be accomplished with a ternary, but that would look ugly.

This is of course only an example, I'm sure there's a better way to write this; however I'm specifically wondering about this use-case.

```
var getNumbers = function(getNumbers) {
    return function(e) {
        if (getNumbers) {
            return !isNaN(e) ? e : null;
        } else {
            return isNaN(e) ? e : null;
        }
    };
};

var data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '1', '2', '3', '4'];

console.log(data.filter(getNumbers(true)));
console.log(data.filter(getNumbers(false)));
```

Output:

```
[ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]
```

Comment: I have rollback-ed your post because you are not allowed to make changes to your code after you have received an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using a function name as a variable name inside said function

This can be very confusing to someone reading your code(or you after having been away from your code for awhile)

Hither forth, getNumbers (the variable in the function) shall be referred to as showNumbers

## XOR it baby

XOR is exactly what the current logic is doing anyway.

When showNumber is true invert other boolean value

```
//showNumber = true
T ^ showNumber == F
F ^ showNumber == T
```

Else leave as it was

```
//showNumber = false
T ^ showNumber == T
F ^ showNumber == F

var getNumbers = function(showNumbers) {
    return function(e) {
        return isNaN(e) ^ showNumbers ? e : null;
    };
};
```

## Potential gotcha

Javascripts XOR(^) is bitwise NOT Logical

Comment: Updated original code for better parameter name.

Comment: Yeah, using XOR would be the cleanest approach, but definitely not readable to everyone. I'm marking this as the answer as this is definitely the "best" way.